# Where is the appropriate place to ask a question about career development?

Tags: discussion, support, site-recommendation

I could really use some advice on my current employment situation (web developer) and whether it is helpful or harmful for me at this point. I'm not sure where I should ask such a question.

Comment: http://www.reddit.com/r/webdev

Comment: @random - Thanks! I think this is actually my accepted answer...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, questions that are specific to *just you* are not really appropriate for the Stack Exchange format. Perhaps you could try finding a local peer group and discussing the question over a beer or other socially acceptable beverage of your choice.

Comment: Only issue is I don't have any friends in similar fields. This is definitely a question specific to the industry, and I'm sure I'm not the only one in this situation!

Answer (score 7):

Depends what your question is, but generally career development is on topic on [The Workplace](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/). It's not an IT specific site, so keeping your questions generally applicable is a plus, but you can get an impression of what's on topic by browsing the questions and our [career development](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/career-development?sort=newest&pagesize=15) tag.

Expect advice from experts in *professional matters* not necessarily other programmers, but we have some [software industry](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software-industry) related questions and users.